# Which text delivers clearer message to users

Tags: text

we are going to provide an in-app purchase item, so that user can unlock every blocked features in the app. However, this doesn't include removing ads-free.

In order to ensure users really understand what they are going to pay for, I was wondering, which text delivers clearer message?

> Everything, without ad-free: Cloud, summary chart, dividend chart,
>   zoomable chart, selectable chart period, watchlists + portfolios,
>   news, background alert, currency exchange and upcoming features.

OR

> Everything, except ad-free: Cloud, summary chart, dividend chart,
>   zoomable chart, selectable chart period, watchlists + portfolios,
>   news, background alert, currency exchange and upcoming features.

We do bold and italic on `without ad-free:` and `except ad-free:`

It looks like

[image]

[image]

May I know, is using "without" clearer to you, or using "except" clearer to you?

Thank you.

Comment: Ugh, you business model sucks. There are too many options, and if the user is paying you any money AT ALL you should remove ads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using confusing Grammar prepositions such as Except/ Without, make it clear to the user of what's in the package and what's not.

Replace it with clearer terms: **REMOVE ADS** or **CONTAINS ADS.**

It makes sense since you're developing on Android and Play Store already uses these terms.

[image]

Also, as per hierarchy, your **PREMIUM** package should always be present at the Top so that the user can UNLOCK everything at once. You've made Premium Lite the most important package option so if a user wants to buy something they will pick the Lite package over the Premium and might not like that Ads are still present.

Also, instead of Premium and Premium Lite. Make the purchase packages: Premium and Lite.

I got a little free time to make a quick mockup for you :)

[image: options mockup]

You need not specify OR because those are two buttons and not a selection meaning only one can be pressed.

Apart from that, I've excluded the Share symbol. You should include it.

Comment: Our business strategy is encourage users go for lite instead of premium. Should we place lite on the top?

Comment: Let the price for the Lite package do that. As you can see, you need not put Lite on the top to get the user's attention towards it, referring to the mock-up. You could also test this behaviour with a few users before pushing it as an update for better judgement.

Comment: This is clearer than the OP's.  But it doesn't quite state that Lite has everything that Premiium has while keeping the ads.  Maybe just state that: "Unlock all features, but keep the ads"

Comment: The fact your business model can be misunderstood in the first place points to a bigger problem.  I would try and get it down to 2 options... **Premium** - `Unlock all features and removes ads`, **Basic** - `Unlock all features and contains ads`  (+1 for being the best option without changing business models)

Answer (score 2):

"Except" would be clearer and more grammatically correct: 'ad free' is the exception to 'everything'. Very straightforward.

A reasonable interpretation of "everything without ad-free" could be "every one of these things is without ad-free", i.e. "each of these things has ads".  Which is not exactly what you mean -- it's close enough that it wouldn't be *disastrously* bad wording, but it's a bit more convoluted than the alternative (and verges on a double negative: 'without without ads').

For comparison, think of "everything without peanuts" vs "everything except peanuts".  With that it's a little more obvious that the first implies "each thing has no peanuts" and the second "all the things, except for peanuts".

Answer (score 1):

*Except* is definitely the right word here.  I would also italicize *Everything*, and leave out the comma: *Everything except ad-free*.  That has more punch, and draws more attention to *Everything*.

All that said, I would seriously consider some form of Swapnil's suggestion.